# Expected number of random rows needed to get a full-rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I have a random $m \times n$ matrix over $F_2$ of full rank (i.e. all columns are independent) 
where $m$ << $n$.

Now, I wish to randomly choose $k$ rows such that the corresponding sub-matrix (that is made only of the chosen rows) will be of full rank (i.e. rank $m$) with high probability, and I wonder how large $k$ should be in order for that to happen with constant probability.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: So $m > n$? Then you can never achieve rank $m$. Your submatrix can at most have rank $\min\{n,k\}$. You should first properly describe the setting.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. m << n. The original matrix is of full rank (i.e. rank m). I wish to take $k$ rows that the corresponding submatrix will have rank $m$ and I wonder how many random rows I need to take for that to happen in constant probability (for $k=n$ this will happen in probability 1..)

Comment: "i.e. all columns are independent" Think about that again. And when you take $k$ out of $m$ rows, your matrix has rank $k$. I repeat myself: You should first properly describe the setting. What you write is totally confusing.

Comment: I'm not so sure what is the problem.. the matrix is of size $m \times n$ (i.e. the matrix has $m$ columns and $n$ rows). The matrix is is of full rank (i.e. rank $m$ since $m$ << $n$). Now, I randomly choose $k$ rows $l_1, l_2, ..., l_k$ and look at the $m\times k$ matrix whose rows are $l_1,...,l_k$ and I wish to get an upper bound on $k$ (as a function of $n,m$) for which the above mentioned $m\times k$ matrix as full rank (i.e. rank $m$) 

What's not clear about the setting?

Comment: One problem is that an $\ m\times n\ $ matrix has $\ m $ *rows* and $\ n\ $ *columns*, not the other way round.  From what you write in your second paragraph, it would appear that what you have in mind is actually an $\ n\times m\ $ matrix.